# Grep moving spaces?

Tags: shell, unix, grep

```
{
while read -r  line ; do
   if grep -q '2015' $line
     then
      echo "inside then"
      echo "$line"
      echo "yes"
   fi
   done
} < testinput
```

Once I execute the above code the output is:

```
inside then
( nothing is printed in this line its spaces)  
yes
```

Why is that input line is not getting printed in the second output line?
Your help is appreciated. The reason why I am asking is that I actually have to perform a few operations on the input line after the match using grep is successful.

Input file Sample :

```
2015-07-18-00.07.28.991321-240 I84033A497         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 21233902             TID  : 9510        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: xxxxxxxx             NODE : 000         DB   : XXXXXXX
APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.xxxxxxx.150718040727
AUTHID  : XXXXXXXX
EDUID   : 9510                 EDUNAME: db2agent (XXXXXXXX) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, SQLHA APIs for DB2 HA Infrastructure
```

I need to capture the time when SQLHA shows up in the input file or log file. To do that first I find the match for time in the input file and then I save that time in the variables. Once I find SQLHA I will write the time saved in the variables into an output file. So for every occurrence of SQLHA in the log, I will write the time to the output file.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You seem to be reading file names from the file, and then looking to see if any of the digits 0, 1, 2, or 5 appear in the file?  Is that really what you intended (did you mean `grep -q '2015'`)?  If there's a blank line in your input, though, then you're going to blow everything away.  The `grep` will read the rest of the standard input (which is redirected from `testinput`), and then the `read` will fail.  The `{ … } < testinput` notation certainly works — I often advocate it — but it would be possible to just use `done < testinput` without the braces.

Comment: I think you should be debugging with `bash -x yourscript.sh` so you see what the code is up to.  You might be meaning to use `grep -q 2015 <<< "$line"` — that would be effective though inefficient.  Alternatively, you should add `echo "Line: [[$line]]" >&2` after the `read` and before the `if`.  But you should probably be using `grep -q 2015 testinput | while read -r line; do …; done`, with some minor caveats about setting variables in the body of the loop but they won't be accessible after the loop unless you go to some lengths (`shopt -s lastpipe`) to make them available.

Comment: "if grep -q '2015' $line" ->
is $line a filename?  Probably not.  You might want to echo "$line" piped into grep instead.

Comment: @jimmcnamara $line will have one line from input file.I needto search for 2015 for every lien in teh input file and then extact teh date and time form that line and save it into temp variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You were already told once before to add the material to the question; you should do that.  We ask comments — you edit the question so the comments become obsolete.  I've transferred the comment for you, and spell-fixed it, this time — please do it yourself in future.

Comment: @anubhava The solution that  you provided worked and it has writen the line in the output but still why is that after i used grep command $line is filled with spaces.   {
             while read -r line ; do

            if [[ $line == *2015* ]];
              then
               echo "inside then"
              echo $line
               echo "yes"
               fi
               done
             } < testinput

Comment: @StevenPenny solution from anubhava has worked but curious to know why the grep command moved spaces into the $line.Appreciate your help and i have pasted the input file in teh question.

Comment: Are you sure the line read wasn't blank/empty?  If there's a blank line in your input, you will wreck everything — as [already stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620886/grep-moving-spaces/31621113#comment51190935_31620886).  Your approach is not good; it is very expensive.  You don't need it to be as expensive as it is — I've outline 3 main solutions in my answer, with 3 variants for the 'shell only' solution.  Have you run your script with `bash -x` or equivalent?  If not, why not?  It is a basic way of debugging shell scripts, but also one of the most informative.

Comment: @anubhava this is the  output                                                                    inside then
2015-07-18-00.07.28.991321-240 I84033A497 LEVEL: Info
yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update about what is really wanted, it is fairly clear that
you should probably use `awk`, though `sed` would also be an option (but harder).  You can do it in shell too, though that's messier.

```
awk '/^2015-/ { datetime = $1 } / SQLHA / { print datetime }' testinput
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^2015-/ {s/ .*//; h; n; }' -e '/ SQLHA / { x; p; x; }' testinput
```

(If you find `2015-` at the start of a line, remove the stuff after a space and save it in the hold space.  If you find `SQLHA` with spaces on either side, swap the hold and pattern space (thus placing the saved date/time in the pattern space), then print it, then switch it back.  The switch back means that if two lines contain SQLHA between occurrences of the date line, you'll get the same date printed twice, rather than a date and then the first of the SQLHA lines.  You end up having to think about what can go wrong, as well as what to do when everything goes right — but that may be more for later than right now.)

Using just `sh`:

```
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
    (2015-*) datetime=$(set -- $line; echo $1);;  # Absence of quotes is deliberate
    (*SQLHA*) echo "$datetime";;
    esac
done < testinput
```

There are many other ways to do that in shell.  Some of them are safer than this.  It'll work on the data shown safely, but you might get to run against maliciously created data.

```
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
    (2015-*) datetime=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/ .*//');;
    (*SQLHA*) echo "$datetime";;
    esac
done < testinput
```

This invokes `sed` once per date line.  Using Bash, I guess you can use:

```
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
    (2015-*) datetime="${line/ */}";; # Replace blank and everything after with nothing
    (*SQLHA*) echo "$datetime";;
    esac
done < testinput
```

This is the least likely to go wrong and avoids executing an external command for each line.  You could also avoid `case`…`esac` using `if` and probably `[[` so as to get pattern matching.  Etc.

---

Running your script on a Mac, I get error output such as:

```
grep: 2015-07-18-00.07.28.991321-240: No such file or directory
grep: I84033A497: No such file or directory
grep: LEVEL:: No such file or directory
```

Are you not seeing that?  If you're not, then either you've sent errors to `/dev/null` (or some other location than the terminal) or you've not shown us exactly the code you're using — or there's a blank line at the top of your `testinput` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the different options you have provided which are more effcient than what I have started with.Getting o/p with one single line of command is really awesome. I will also get back and see why initially i got error using grep. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what your script is trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/2015/ {
  print "inside then"
  print
  print "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have written(very basic).I will try to run the same program with Grep and post why i am getting the blank space soon.

```
    while read -r  line
       do
      if [[ $line == *2015* ]];
       then
       dtime=`echo $line | cut -c1-26`
      fi
      if [[ $line == *SQLHA* ]];
       then
       echo $dtime
      fi
      done
     } < testinput
```

Input Used:

```
      2015-07-18-00.07.28.991321-240 I84033A497         LEVEL: Info
      EDUID   : 9510                 EDUNAME: db2agent (SIEB_RPT) 0
      FUNCTION: DB2 Common,APIs for DB2 HA Infrastructure, sqlhaAmIin 
      2015-07-18-00.07.29.991321-240 I84033A497         LEVEL: Info
      FUNCTION: DB2 Common, SQLHA APIs for DB2 HA Infrastructure, sqlha 
      2015-07-18-00.07.48.991321-240 I84033A497         LEVEL: Info
      EDUID   : 9510                 EDUNAME: db2agent (SIEB_RPT) 0
      FUNCTION: DB2 Common, SQLHA APIs for DB2 HA Infrastructure, sqlha
```

O/p :

```
     2015-07-18-00.07.29.991321
     2015-07-18-00.07.48.991321
```